# Get array values from Json format Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, twitter

How can I get the array values return by a Json format in twitter. I've already know how to handle json format from yahoo and fb but, the json format returned by twitter is different with a callback function.

fb

```
my({
   "data": [{
            "name": "May Ann Salle",
            "created_time": "2012-01-09T12:29:19+0000"
           }]
});
```

twitter

```
my([
      {
        "recipient_screen_name": "1stone"
      },
      {
        "recipient_screen_name": "2ndone"
      }
]);



$.each(my, function(i, tw) { 
        disp += tw.recipient_screen_name;   
});

alert(disp);
```

but I only get the 1st one, I'm unable to get the 2nd one of array.

Comment: You're missing a comma in the second example between your objects. Also, what is `my`?

Comment: @Joe forget to type that, but in actual output there is. my is the callback function.

Comment: Your code works fine as-is, what problem are you having?  http://jsfiddle.net/BnCVU/

Comment: @Rocket I can only get the first array, It seems that in the each function I have only one array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mention this is about **JSON-P** not just JSON.

Anyway, you'll probably need different callbacks for each data-set.

```
// your callback function
function myTwitterCb(data) {
  var disp = ""
  var len = data.length
  var tw = {} // placeholder object
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tw = data[i]
    disp += tw.recipient_screen_name
  }
  doSomethingElseWith(disp)
}

function myFacebookCb(response) {
  var data = response.data
  var len = data.length
  var fb = {} // placeholder object
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    fb = data[i]
    disp += fb.name
  }
  doSomethingElseWith(disp)


}

function doSomethingElseWith(disp) {
  // draw it to the screen or something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var disp, i = 0, l = tw.length;
for(i; i < l; i++) {
    disp += tw[i].recipient_screen_name;
}

alert(disp);
```